# View a PDF with two columns by displaying it one column by one column

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to view a PDF with two columns by displaying it column by column? I can certainly use any viewer to look at such a document but leafing around from column-to-column is very cumbersome. Even more so for scanned-in bitmaps.

The layout of many Android devices would be ideal to read a single column at a time.

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? You have a PDF with 2 columns, and you want to view it as 1 column only? Or you have PDF with 2 columns, and you want to view the 2 columns in 1 page?

Comment: @geffchang: I have a docment with 2 columns and I want to read them, viewing only ~1 column at a time. Currently, I do this manually, going to the next page, enlarging it accordingly, which is very cumbersome.

Comment: KOreader has very customizable view by columns, see here: https://koreader.rocks/user_guide/#readingpdfs

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF are scanned images (pure image), I don't think it's possible.

But if it's purely text (like a Word document saved as a PDF file), you can use [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader) (or its free version). When you open the PDF, click the More Options button at the lower right, and select `Text Reflow`. This time, you will only see 1 column.

*I'm not sure what happens if there's a combination of text and picture.*

Comment: Reflow is not an answer, because it ruins the layout of technical documents that are typically set with Latex. Many eInk readers have addons or apps that show one column at a time, even if the document is scanned, so there must be one for Android too.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [EBookDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid). It supports view two column document as one column by cropping and moving the parts of a page around. It's perfdct on mobile phones but probably not idea for pads.